# Python venv using system python?

Tags: python, python-venv

Why does `python -m venv py38` use the system python still??

[image]

This just burned my pretty severely, I had a very customized python 3.8 environment that I thought was isolated from the system as advertised by `venv`, my system python just upgraded to 3.9 and now I have to re-build everything.

Any suggestions on a way to create actually isolated python environments would be appreciated.

Comment: why not keep 3.8 if you want to use it? There is no problem to have both 3.8 and 3.9.

Comment: That's just how virtual environments work. It isolates from the system's site-packages, but it reuses the interpreter. For a higher level of isolation, consider docker?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "as advertised", the docs say:  *Running this command creates ... a bin (or Scripts on Windows) subdirectory containing a copy/symlink of the Python binary/binaries*

Comment: The problem (as seen in the screenshot) is that venv did not link to python 3.8, it linked to python3, thereby not creating an isolated environment. When the system updated to 3.9 (in an update I missed) it hosed the venv. I have since switched to anaconda as it creates isolated environments. I will look at removing this question as on reflection I dont think its appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

> Running this command creates the target directory (creating any parent directories that don’t exist already) and places a pyvenv.cfg file in it with a home key pointing to the Python installation from which the command was run (a common name for the target directory is .venv). It also creates a bin (or Scripts on Windows) subdirectory containing a copy/symlink of the Python binary/binaries (as appropriate for the platform or arguments used at environment creation time).

This makes me think that it's possible to have not a copy of the python installation but a link to it.

Anyway pyenv.cfg should have the path of your python, I suggest to change it.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer but there is a fundamental problem I see with Venv then, `copy/symlink ` are actually two completely different actions, `copy` would create isolation, `symlink` does not, and it looks like by default `symlink` is the norm and basically breaks the point of using Venv. Thank you for the response and note from the documents explaining this odd behavior.